# PHP echoing in wrong location of html

Tags: php, html, include, echo

I'm attempting to make a template based system to deliver content but I've run into a problem that I just can't seem to solve. When I try to echo out variables that have data from includes it gets outputted in the wrong section of my html.

Below is 'newstuff.php' which is my page to be executed on the browser, the offending variables are `$php $head $content`.

```
<?php

$php = include "templates/content/newstuff/phpCode.php";
$head = include "templates/content/newstuff/head.html";
$content = include "templates/content/newstuff/content.php";

include realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/templates/templateMain.php';
?>
```

Below is 'tempalteMain.php' this is my tempalte. Note the location of the echoing of `$php $head $content`.

```
<?php
echo $php;
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <?php echo $head; ?> 
    </head>

    <body class="body1" onload="inputBlur2()">
        <div class="borderLine"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>

        <div class="mainContent1" >

            <div class="header1" >

                <div class="headerContainer" >

                    <ul class="navList1">
                        <li><a id = "B0"  href="index.php">New Stuff</a></li>
                        <li><a id = "B1"  href="MainPage.php">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a id = "B2"  href="ProjectsPage.php">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a id = "B3"  href="AOrdering.php">About Ordering</a></li> 
                        <li><a id = "B4"  href="ContactMe.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a id = "B5"  href="FAQPage.php">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a id = "B6" href="SCart.php">My Cart</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content1"> 
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is 'head.html' this provides the code to be delivered by the `$head` PHP variable.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../StylePR.css">
<title>KickUp Electronics</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Below is 'content.php' this provides the code to be delivered by the `$content` PHP variable.

```
<p>Welcome to the new stuff page!!!</p>
```

Finally, this is the page source that gets outputted taken from the chrome DOM editor. Note the locations of the information from content.php are wrong and there are strange '1's that are echoed out (also, when viewing the page source, the information from head.html is placed outside the html tags).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/../StylePR.css">
        <title>KickUp Electronics</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="body1" onload="inputBlur2()">
<p>Welcome to the new stuff page!!!</p> <!--Wrong Location!-->
1





        1 



        <div class="borderLine"></div>
        <div class="banner"></div>

        <div class="mainContent1">

            <div class="header1">

                <div class="headerContainer">

                    <ul class="navList1">
                        <li><a id="B0" href="index.php">New Stuff</a></li>
                        <li><a id="B1" href="MainPage.php">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a id="B2" href="ProjectsPage.php">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a id="B3" href="AOrdering.php">About Ordering</a></li> 
                        <li><a id="B4" href="ContactMe.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a id="B5" href="FAQPage.php">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a id="B6" href="SCart.php">My Cart</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="content1"> 
                1            </div>


        </div>

</body></html>
```

I tried searching many times for a solution to no avail. Is this a problem with the echo being executed before the html fully loads? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This won't work. In the way you think.
$php = include "templates/content/newstuff/phpCode.php";
It'll just do the include right away. TBO I would look at a proper template engine for PHP - twig is really good and easy to get started.

Comment: Include in the place you want the file. `include` returns a true/false, not the contents of the file.

Comment: @Richard Housham funny that u mentioned twig, i tried it then realized you couldnt include php code :(

Comment: It's a bit tricky in 600 chars but basically you have this kind of layout. 
$config (connection, setup to twig files)
$logic (get the data, process if required)
$display (send data to twig and let it display) 

It's the separation that is what you get. I know it's a bit tricky to get started but trust me it's really good. You can have multiple templates, inherited templates. It's really good to learn and you will love it when you do. It's quite a small language as well, and is really just making PHP in the backend, so you kinda know what it's doing.

Comment: You can reuse code snippets as well, lots of good things and it will lead you into a good design pattern

Comment: Ya i rushed in with twig without fully understanding it i guess. I do have some familiarity because i dabbled in the Django framework for python. I'll go look up some tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using includes wrong.

```
$php = include "templates/content/newstuff/phpCode.php";
```

is *immediately* outputting the output of that file, and setting `$php` to `1` (i.e. "it worked!").

> Handling Returns: include returns `FALSE` on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return `1`. - http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to capture the output, but a better solution is probably moving the `include` calls directly into `templateMain.php`.

Comment: Side note: Consider a proper framework like Laravel, where the templating engine will handle stuff like this for you in a best-practices manner.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i got it to work by setting the variable to the path of the file, then included instead of echoed with the variable in the templateMain.php